# How to using php count the word pair (string) array insert into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

two array sample

```
$a=array("a","b","c","d");
$b=array("b","c","d","f");
```

and  I use for loop to produce this outcome

```
ab ac ad af bb bc bd bf cb cc cd cf db dc dd df
```

one array $a element align an element of array $b

and I want to count the element to this solution
the problem is I want bd and db as a same thing ,we recognize it appear two times
how can i do it in php ?
after that , I will record all the count solution insert into MySQL

Comment: You want db and bd will count as same thing, Its mean that cd and dc two? and so on? or this is the inputs and just bd and db and thats all.

Comment: bd and db count as same thing ,and cd and dc too.

Comment: sort them, then see if they're in your result array already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick answer - sort your two elements before you combine them, then check if they already exist in the answer set.

```
$a=array("a","b","c","d");
$b=array("b","c","d","f");

$res = array();
foreach($a as $v1) {
  foreach($b as $v2) {
    $t = array($v1, $v2);
    asort($t);
    $val = implode('', $t);
    if(!in_array($val, $res))
      $res[] = $val;
  }
}
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The better algorithm would be to produce only valid strings end of for loop.

Let me explain before.

$a=array("a","b","c","d");

$b=array("b","c","d","f");

$x=array_diff($a,$b);  //X will have elements "a" alone.

$y=array_uintersect ()//Check syntax. will give you matches "b""c""d"

In the forloop you use , use $x instead of $a .

This will produce following result "ab ac ad af"

And $y has the matches . So you can make use of it to produce "bb","cc","dd"

If you want count alone then the answer you want is count(matches) + result of your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$a = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
$b = array("b", "c", "d", "f");

sort($a);
sort($b);

$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < (count($b)); $j++) {
        if ($b[$j] < $a[$i]) {
            continue;
        }
        $result[] = $a[$i] . $b[$j];
    }
}

$result = array_unique($result, SORT_STRING);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: This doesn't works, the result for your script is:  
    array(6) { [0]=> string(2) "bb" [1]=> string(2) "cb" [2]=> string(2) "cc" [3]=> string(2) "db" [4]=> string(2) "dc" [5]=> string(2) "dd" }

"ab" is solution and isn't included there.

Comment: $result show the unique array and how to count the number before or after the array_unique() ?

Comment: @lcjury sorry, it should be `$b[$i] < $a[$j]` but not `$a[$i] < $b[$j]`. Fixed.

Comment: @FrederickZhang Still wrong, it will return repeated results.

Comment: @黃一航 If you need the number only, then the `$result` becomes unnecessary. Just apply `array_unique` to the two original arrays, then `number=C[x=count(a), y=count(b)]=(x!)/(y!(x-y)!) (x>=y)`

Comment: @lcjury sorry again... fixed. forgot to change the index of the array together

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
 <?php
$a=array("a","b","c","d");
$b=array("b","c","d","f");
$c=array();
$d=array();
$ii=0;
foreach($a as $dat){
    if(!isset($c[$dat])){
        $c[$dat]=$ii;
        $ii++;
    }
}
foreach($b as $dat){
    if(!isset($c[$dat])){
        $c[$dat]=$ii;
        $ii++;
    }
}
$count=0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < (count($b)); $j++) {
        if(!isset($d[$c[$a[$i]]][$c[$b[$j]]])){
            echo $a[$i].$b[$j]."<br/>";
            $d[$c[$a[$i]]][$c[$b[$j]]]=1;
            $d[$c[$b[$j]]][$c[$a[$i]]]=1;
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
echo "The count is: ".$count;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=array("a","b","c","d");
$b=array("b","c","d","f");
$y=array_intersect($a,$b);
print_r ($y);
$req=count($a)*count($b) - count($y);//13
echo $req;
```