# How to using php to get unique word pair(string) and insert into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

code :

```
$a=array("apple","bird","cat","dog");
$b=array("bird","cat","dog","flog");

$res = array();
foreach($a as $v1) {
  foreach($b as $v2) {
    $t = array($v1, $v2);
    asort($t);
    $val = implode('', $t);
    if(!in_array($val, $res))
      print $val;
      print "/";
  }
}
```

the code is rewrite by @pala_ form this article 
[How to using php count the word pair (string) array insert into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788860/how-to-using-php-count-the-word-pair-string-array-insert-into-mysql/29789697#29789697)

and here 's the output

```
applebird/applecat/appledog/appleflog/birdbird/birdcat/birddog/birdflog/birdcat/catcat/catdog/catflog/birddog/catdog/dogdog/dogflog/
```

ok,and my question is if I want to split this combine string into two string

for example :
applebird ----> apple   bird  and insert into MySQL table

like:

**source | target**

apple  |  bird

apple  |  cat

apple  |  dog

........something like that ,any idea ? thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why did you combine these two arrays if you want to split them in your table? It would be easier if you started by inserting a[1] for example to the source column and then generated a loop for array b to the target. I don't know if this is what you need.

Comment: the original question asked for unique combinations, i assume that is still the case.. (ie, treat birdcat the same as catbird)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the implode, store them as a multidimensional array instead.:

```
$a=array("apple","bird","cat","dog");
$b=array("bird","cat","dog","flog");

$res = array();
foreach($a as $v1) {
  foreach($b as $v2) {
    $t = array($v1, $v2);
    asort($t);    
    if(!in_array($t, $res)) {
      print $res[] = $t;
      // alternatively, instead of building them into an array for further processing
      // you could immediately execute your sql query here, using $t[0], $t[1] as
      // the values (thanks to comments).  If you are using prepared statements
      // (which you should be), if you prepare the statement outside of the loops
      // you can simply execute it here, passing $t[0] and $t[1] as the bound parameters
    }
  }
}

foreach($res as $pair) {
  ...
  // build your query using whatever mysql interface you are using
  // $pair[0] will be one word, $pair[1] will be the other
}
```

Comment: You could just insert values $v1 & $v2 after `$res[] = $t;`, would save having to do another loop

Comment: true, i'll add that as an option

Answer (score 0):

I did little modification on your code you may need this:

```
<?php
$a=array("apple","bird","cat","dog");
$b=array("bird","cat","dog","flog");

$res=array();
$finalString="";
foreach($a as $v1) {
  foreach($b as $v2) {
    $t=array($v1,$v2);
    asort($t);
    $val=implode('|',$t);
    if(!in_array($val, $res))
      $finalString.=$val."/";
  }
}
echo $finalString;
?>
```

Out put:

apple|bird/apple|cat/apple|dog/apple|flog/bird|bird/bird|cat/bird|dog/bird|flog/bird|cat/cat|cat/cat|dog/cat|flog/bird|dog/cat|dog/dog|dog/dog|flog/

further you may explode this based on "/"

This may help you.

Comment: why are you checking `in-array($val, $res)` when you never add anything to `$res`? do you even understand the code you are adding as an answer?